# Adding UUIDs to my Django app yields a NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

I have a `books` app using a UUID with a listview of all books and detailview of individual books. I keep getting the following error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /books/
Reverse for 'book_detail' with arguments '('/books/71fcfae7-bf2d-41b0-abc8-c6773930a44c',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['books/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$']
```

Here is the `models.py` file:

```
# books/models.py
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('book_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

The `urls.py` file where I'm using  to convert the `id` from the model to a `uuid`.

```
 # books/urls.py
 from django.urls import path

from .views import BookListView, BookDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', BookListView.as_view(), name='book_list'),
    path('<uuid:pk>', BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book_detail'),
]
```

The top-level `urls.py` file looks like this and adds a `books/` route.

```
# urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('books/', include('books.urls')),
```

The `views.py` file:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Book

class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    template_name = 'books/book_list.html'

class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book'
    template_name = 'books/book_detail.html'
```

And the relevant templates file.

```
<!-- templates/book_detail.html -->
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for book in book_list %}
<div>
  <h2><a href="{% url 'book_detail' book.get_absolute_url %}">{{ book.title }}</a></h2>
</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I believe I'm implementing this correctly but the URL is not liking my UUID. What is amiss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not "adding uuid". The problem is that you are doing the URL reversal twice: once in `get_absolute_url` and once in the `{% url %}` tag. Use one or the other, not both.

Either:

```
<a href="{% url 'book_detail' book.pk %}">{{ book.title }}</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}">{{ book.title }}</a>
```